# MongoDB best practice to count related documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I was wondering what is the best practice to get a count of related documents of a particular document in MongoDB.

Scenario is as follows:
I need to get posts that users shared and I need to get total number of comments related to those posts as well.

I would like to use the MongoDB Aggregation way if possible (if that is the best way of doing it)
I am aware how to perform this query using separate methods .count() and .find().

document in posts collection:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('5a66321e7e2043078bc3b88a'),
    uid: 'UniqueIDofTheUser',
    text: 'Post text'
}
```

document in comments collection

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('5a66321e7e2043078bc3b88c'),
    uid: 'UniqueIDofTheUser',
    post_id: ObjectId('5a66321e7e2043078bc3b88a'),
    text: 'Comment text'
}
```

Desired Result:

```
[
    {
        _id: ObjectId('5a66321e7e2043078bc3b88a'),
        uid: 'UniqueIDofTheUser',
        text: 'Post text',
        commentsCount: 20
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId('5a66321e7e2043078bc3b88c'),
        uid: 'UniqueIDofTheUser',
        text: 'Another post',
        commentsCount: 3
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId('5a6632e17e2043078bc3b88f'),
        uid: 'UniqueIDofTheUser',
        text: 'Some random post',
        commentsCount: 4
    },
]
```

Comment: You can just do a `$lookup` to pull the posted comments for each post with `$size` on the returned comments for a count. Something like `db.posts.aggregate([{
                    $lookup:
                    {
                        from: "comments",
                        localField: "_id",
                        foreignField: "post_id",
                        as: "commentsCount"
                    }
                }, {
    $addFields: {
        "commentsCount": {
            $size: "$commentsCount"
        }
    }
}])`

Comment: Hi @Veeram you saved my day. Thank you so much! I would mark this as correct answer, unless there was another answer with reasonable description of why to do it another way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just do a `$lookup` to pull the posted comments for each post with `$size` on the returned comments for a count.

```
db.posts.aggregate(
 [{ $lookup: { 
    from: "comments", 
    localField: "_id", 
    foreignField: "post_id", 
    as: "commentsCount" 
 } }, 
 { $addFields: { "commentsCount": { $size: "$commentsCount" } } }]
)
```