# MongoDB: Count number of occurrence of document in collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to count referenced documents in other collection, like I have following scenario:

Books:

```
{
  id: "123",
  name: "Alpha"
}, {
  id: "124",
  name: "Beta"
}, {
  id: "125",
  name: "Gamma"
}
```

Users:

```
{
  id: "234",
  name: "user 1"
  fav_books: ["123", "124"]
}, {
  id: "235",
  name: "user 1"
  fav_books: ["123", "124", "125"]
}, {
  id: "236",
  name: "user 1"
  fav_books: ["123", "125"]
},
```

I need to count each book count in all users collection, Like above scenario should output:

```
{
  "123": "3",
  "124": "2",
  "125": "2"
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB best practice to count related documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48389112/mongodb-best-practice-to-count-related-documents)

Comment: Try `db.Books.aggregate(  [{ $lookup: {      from: "Users",      localField: "id",      foreignField: "fav_books",      as: "bookscount"   } },   { $project: { "id":1, "bookscount": { $size: "$bookscount" } } }] )`

Comment: @SirajulHaq did my answer help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running mongodb 3.4 onwards:

```
db.Users.aggregate( [ 
          { $unwind: "$fav_books" }, 
          { $sortByCount: "$fav_books" }
          ] )
```

No need to do a join. You have an array of book id's within each Users document... unless you wanted to display the Books name.

Above code outputs:

```
{
    "_id" : "123",
    "count" : 3
}
{
    "_id" : "125",
    "count" : 2
}
{
    "_id" : "124",
    "count" : 2
}
```